# How to load content from iCloud or other server to viewController in App

Tags: ios, icloud

I am developing an App that shows annotations with popovers that appear when the user taps the detailDisclosureButton.  I am thinking that the details should come from a server so that if new locations had to be added (i.e. more annotations on the map) and therefore new details content had to be added, that this could somehow be done from iCloud or some other server in order to update the App.

How does one go about connecting information that sits on a server (say html and photos, plus location data) to the App?  Are there specific data access methods for connecting to the server that would exist in my viewController class?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) - it's great for server connection stuff. There are plenty of tutorials with this.

Comment: This tutorial is good as a starting point: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/